# Angular: Why called google-maps my function in interpolation?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, maps

Everytime I hover or interact with the map, my function "getTitle()" is called countless times, but why?
I use "@angular/google-maps": "^14.2.2"

map.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-map',
templateUrl: './map.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private map?: google.maps.Map;
    private center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
    private zoom: number;
    
    constructor() {
        this.center = { lat: 47.280622, lng: 8.638879 };
        this.zoom = 15;
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initializeMap();
    }
    
    initializeMap() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
            center: this.center,
            zoom: this.zoom,
        });
    }
    
    private title: string = "Title";
    private count: number = 0;
    getTitle(): string {
        console.log(this.count, 'DEBUG');
        this.count += 1;
        return this.title;
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
    }
}
```

map.component.html

```html
<div id="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="list">
    <code>
      {{ getTitle() }}
    </code>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't explain how this function is called by Google Maps. I hope someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functions in your template, angular change detection on default cant "remember" the return and rerun your function on every changedetection run happen in your application.

Calling functions in your template can be have a heavy impact on performance.

So its better to use `this.title` as a direct binding in your template.

Edit:
Something to read about it: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496